# Why does adb shell pm list permissions -g list more permissions than adb shell pm list permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, adb

As the title implies,

```
adb shell pm list permissions -g
```

returns more permissions than

```
adb shell pm list permissions
```

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `pm list permissions` without `-g` prints only *ungrouped* permissions. Here are the results from one of my phones:

Number of permissions printed out by`pm list permissions`:

```
$ pm list permissions | grep 'permission:' | wc -l
476
```

matches number of permissions in the `ungrouped` section of `pm list permissions -g`:

```
$ pm list permissions -g | sed -n '/ungrouped:/,$ p' | grep 'permission:' | wc -l
476
```

And when combined with the number permissions which belong to some group:

```
$ pm list permissions -g | sed -n '1,/ungrouped:/p' | grep 'permission:' | wc -l
33
```

It adds to the total number of permissions printed out by `pm list permissions -g`:

```
$ pm list permissions -g | grep 'permission:' | wc -l
509
```